# How is the copy assignment function accessing private members of the other object (Stroustroup Principles and Practice book)?

Tags: c++, oop, vector, copy-constructor

I've been reading through Chapter 18.3.2 of "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++, 2nd Edition", which describes the vector copy assignment operation. Here is the idea presented in the book:

```
class vector {
          int sz;
          double* elem;
public:
          vector& operator=(const vector&) ;         // copy assignment
          // . . .
};
```

As per this class definition `int sz` and `double* elem` are private members of the `vector` class.

Now the copy assignment is *defined* as:

```
vector& vector::operator=(const vector& a)
          // make this vector a copy of a
{
          double* p = new double[a.sz];              // allocate new space
          copy(a.elem,a.elem+a.sz,elem);            // copy elements
          delete[] elem;                             // deallocate old space
          elem = p;                                  // now we can reset elem
          sz = a.sz;
          return *this;                             // return a self-reference
}
```

I understand this as: `a` is passed as a `const vector&` to the overloaded `operator=` function. But in the second line of the definition, the call to `std::copy()` is able to somehow access `a.elem` and `a.sz`, which I understand are private members of the object referenced by `a`. I just don't understand how this can be possible.

What am I missing here? Thanks ahead for your answers!

Comment: How would you write it if it **couldn't** access members of another object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access control is per-class, not per instance: any member of `A` can access any member of any object of type `A`.  There is an exception in that members of a derived class can access `protected` members of a base class only through an object of the derived type (or through that type itself for static member access).

Comment: Interesting... It makes sense, but my mind is still feeling hesitant to buy into it. So is that purely because the `operation=` is defined within the scope of the vector class?

Comment: @AdityaTB: It’s because it’s a member—the physical location of its definition is irrelevant.

Comment: @AdityaTB Yes, exactly.